# Question that was duplicated on CS.SE and SO

Tags: discussion, specific-question

The question [Largest sum divisible by n](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/53849/755) has been posted both here and on Stack Overflow: [Sum divisible by n](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35530263/781723).  Stack Overflow has declined a flag suggesting that it be closed on Stack Overflow.

Should the question remain open on both sites, in this specific case?  If not, should it be closed here on CS.SE?

---

Potentially secondary factors that may or may not be relevant:

- We have made substantial revisions to the question here on CS.SE which, in my opinion, make our copy a better question (or, at least, better for CS.SE).
- Among the answers received so far, the answers here on CS.SE seem better than the answers on Stack Overflow, in my opinion.
- The problem statement, as quoted, claims this can be solved in $O(n)$ time.  There has been doubt expressed about whether the problem can be solved in $O(n)$ time.  It's not clear whether that has any relevance to this discussion, though.
- For reference, cross-posting on multiple SE sites is generally not allowed: [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/160917).  However, while this policy is a helpful guideline in general, no policy is absolute, so it's worthwhile to consider the specifics.
- The poster not responded yet to requests to provide attribution or a citation to the original source of this question.  It is apparently a challenge at university, according to a current comment here on CS.SE.  (For our reference, here are [our guidelines on referencing](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing).)

Comment: Imho, we should definitely not close. Other than flagging for migration (we would then merge the copies here), there's little to be done. We *could* ask the user to delete their [SO] copy, but that would be rude towards the answerers there.

Answer (score 4):

I think this one falls into the case when a question is appropriate for two sites, **and each version has been tailored for the site's audience**. The SO version comes with JavaScript code, the CS version comes with mathematical notations. It's the same underlying question but asked in somewhat different languages.

I don't think there's any interest in migrating the SO question here: it doesn't have any valuable answers, only answers that say “I don't think you can do better than O(n²)” without offering any argument as to why.